# get position of point given distance from other points?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a 2 points i know the distance between them with a 3rd points. how to get the position of the 3rd point given other distances with the other two points ?

Answer (score 2):

Given only this information, you generally *can't* know the specific point. That third point will be at an intersection of two circles--one centered around each of the other two points. In particular, let's call your first two points $a,b$ and the point you're looking for $c.$ Let $r_{ab}$ be the distance from point $a$ to point $b$, and let $r_{ac},r_{bc}$ be the desired respective distances from $a,b$ to $c$. What we're dealing with, then, is circles around $a$ and $b$ of respective radii $r_{ac}$ and $r_{bc}$.

Now, if two of $r_{ab},r_{ac},r_{bc}$ add up to the third, then there is exactly one point of intersection of the two circles--and that is our point $c$. If two of $r_{ab},r_{ac},r_{bc}$ add up to some number that is **less** than the third, then the circles don't intersect at all, and there is no such point $c$. Otherwise, there will be two points of intersection of the circles, and $c$ will be one of those, but (as I said) there's no way to know which, given only this information.

Comment: But how can you solve for those two points when they do exist?

Comment: Well, assuming that we're in a plane (as I do implicitly in my answer), let $a=(h_a,k_a)$ and $b=(h_b,k_b).$ The point $c$ that we're looking for will be a solution to the following system of equations (if any exist): $$\begin{cases}(x-h_a)^2+(y-k_a)^2=r_{ac}^2 & \\(x-h_b)^2+(y-k_b)^2=r_{bc}^2 & \end{cases}$$ As mentioned in my answer, this system of equations will have either $0,1$ or $2$ solutions. As a side note (if you're wondering how $r_{ab}$ fits into this), we have $$(h_a-h_b)^2+(k_a-k_b)^2=r_{ab}^2.$$

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful but I'm stuck trying to isolate and solve for x and y. Can you explain how to solve for the two equations you listed?

Comment: Just to follow up, I'm trying to write a function that takes the point A, point B, and the lengths to C as input and returns the two possible points. (after checking to make sure two are possible of course)

Comment: Honestly, the solution of the general equation is really ugly. Expanding the squared binomials and subtracting one equation from the other, we see that $$2(h_a-h_b)x+2(k_a-k_b)y+h_b^2-h_a^2+k_b^2-k_a^2=r_{bc}^2-r_{ac}^2.$$ Of course if we have $h_a=h_b$ or $k_a=k_b,$ this becomes fairly simple to solve for whichever of $x,y$ isn't eliminated, at which point we simply substitute back into one of the original equations and solve for the other. Even if not, we can solve readily. Regardless, though, the formulae for the general solutions will be nasty.

Comment: After substitution, we will end up with a quadratic in $x$ or $y,$ which is why we can only have $0,$ $1,$ or $2$ solutions.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I'm off to try and work this out. In my case, I think I can make some assumptions about the known points that will make it a bit easier but I'm not sure yet. Thanks again!

Comment: The assumptions I can make are that $a=(0, 0)$ and $b=(r_{ab}, 0)$ but I still can't figure out how to isolate them.

Comment: Well, if you're assuming that, then the task is made easier. The system becomes $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=r_{ac}^2 & \\(x-r_{ab})^2+y^2=r_{bc}^2, & \end{cases}$$ which is much easier to solve. Can you take it from that point? (The strategy will be much the same, regardless.)

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I can't make the jump to a simple function. $x$ is always positive with these assumptions and $y$ just positive or negative of the same value. Please feel free to respond here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544757/formula-for-solving-for-cx-and-cy-really-need-help and I can give you points for all this help!

Comment: As I said, there will not be a nice answer in general. With your very big assumptions, you get a somewhat nice answer, but usually, it's nasty-looking.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you want a formula, you may have to do a casewise approach: one where $h_a=h_b,$ one where $k_a=k_b,$ and one where $h_a\ne h_b$ and $k_a\ne k_b$. It's possible that a single formula can be adapted that deals with all three cases, but I'll have to think on it after I get some sleep.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much for all the help.